# Flash AS3 Clone, Drag & Drop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I am a teacher and with the help of some of you, I managed to create very basic word game for kids where they are able to create words from letters. [SWF](http://www.jamesjardine.net/ict/sample.swf) | [FLA](http://www.jamesjardine.net/ict/sample.fla)

I have, however, been unable to continue to drag and drop the letters once they have been cloned from their originals on the side of the stage. Is anyone able to advise how I might be able to add this functionality to my existing code?

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

for (var i=1; i<27; i++)
{
    this["object" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStart);
    this["object" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStop);
}    

var sx = 0,sy = 0;

function onStart(e)
{
    sx = e.currentTarget.x;
    sy = e.currentTarget.y;
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}

function onStop(e)
{
    if (e.target.dropTarget != null && 
    e.target.dropTarget.parent == dest)
    {
        var objectClass:Class = 
        getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget)) as Class;
        var copy:MovieClip = new objectClass();
        this.addChild(copy);
        copy.x = e.currentTarget.x;
        copy.y = e.currentTarget.y;
    }

    e.currentTarget.x = sx;
    e.currentTarget.y = sy;
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

I would also love to include a 'bin' where kids can drag letters if they do not wish to have them on stage any more. Any ideas for how I could add this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want similar behavior for dragged object (i.e after dragging, a copy is created)

add these line to your `onStop(e)` like so,

```
copy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStart);
copy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStop);
```

But if you want only dragging and prevent a copy, then either create another function say `dragCopiedObject()` and apply the logic of dragging and not copying in that new function

or

identify between copied or original object in the same `onStop(e)` function and prevent from copying.

If you don't get it then let me know I will explain it to you in detail.

For dropping copied objects inside a bin, after dragging is stopped, check collision with bin object. for more info see,

[`copiedObject.hitTestObject(binObject)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29)

For e.g.

```
if(copiedObject.hitTestObject(binObject)) {

     removeChild(copiedObject);
}
```

UPDATE: To identify between copied objects use `name` property like so:

copy.name = "copy";

I have modified your code,

```
function onStop(e)
{
    if ( e.target.dropTarget != null && 
         e.target.dropTarget.parent == dest && 
         e.currentTarget.name != "copy"         ) //This is newly added
    {
        var objectClass:Class = 
        getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget)) as Class;

        var copy:MovieClip = new objectClass();
        copy.name = "copy"; //This is newly added
        this.addChild(copy);
        copy.x = e.currentTarget.x;
        copy.y = e.currentTarget.y;

        e.currentTarget.x = sx;
        e.currentTarget.y = sy;

        copy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStart);
        copy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStop);
    }    

    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rajneesh. Thanks very much for the advise but I am afraid that I do not understand. I want the letters that have been copied once to be able to be dragged so I think I should 'identify between copied or original object in the same `onStop(e)` function and prevent from copying' but I have no idea how to write the code for this. If you could explain it, I would really appreciate it.